# Keeping Format in Excel When Creating New Workbook

Tags: python, excel, pandas, format, openpyxl

My code:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd


for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.csv')):
    df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)

col_test = df['Test #'].tolist()
col_retest = df['Retest #'].tolist()
data = pd.read_excel('PATH')
start_row = 4

for i, val in enumerate(col_y):
    data.iloc[start_row + i, 21] = val
    i += 1

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output_c.xlsx')
data.to_excel(writer, 'NewSheet')
```

Right now this creates a new workbook with the CSV data entered into the loaded worksheet.

What I want to do is to is to do one of two things, either:

1. Save the worksheet with the new .csv data to the original workbook.
2. Or load all the worksheets from the loaded workbook with their original formatting so that they can all be saved as a new workbook. This is important because the values from the `.csv` data is used in boolean logic statements to fill in another worksheet in the workbook.

How can I do this whilst keeping the formatting?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 1):

As Charlie Clark mentioned you could use [OpenPyXL](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/) to read/write your excel files. There are a few libraries available for reading excel documents, but ime openpyxl is the most robust and the easiest to work with when using pandas. It will preserve any formatting in your excel file (and also preserve macros).

To open a file just do:

```
Workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, read_only=False)
Sheet = Workbook.get_sheet_by_name(sheetname)
```

And to save the file back out:

```
Workbook.save(outputfilename)
```

You can work with the data using openpyxl or as a pandas dataframe. If you add any new rows/columns then those will need to be formatted. They will not just automatically adopt the formatting of the rest of the file like editing within Excel. Openpyxl has a [styles system](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/styles.html) to do your formatting, or you can copy the formatting of adjacent cells with something like this:

```
NewCell.number_format = OldCell.number_format
NewCell.alignment = copy(OldCell.alignment)
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, the normal tools aren't really able to modify or read the formatting form existing Excel files. I can think of a few solutions, though none of them are pretty.

1. Make all of the formatted sheets in your excel file live formulas referencing hidden sheets with unformatted data, so you can just generate the .csv with python and paste the raw data into excel. The downside is that this isn't fully automated.
2. You could read every sheet of the workbook and then re-save it with your additions. The downside is you're only reading the data, not the formatting. You would have to hard-code your formatting with the [xlsxwriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/) package, which is extremely tedious and inflexible.
3. You can use the [win32com](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.3/pywin32/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartClientCom.html) api to open and manipulate Excel programmatically python. You would basically open your workbook in excel and then use commands from that package (that look suspiciously like VBA) to modify the workbook. This is also tedious - in particular, it doesn't integrate with pd.DataFrame.to_excel, so you have to feed it your data by iterating through dataframes. The easiest thing would probably be to write a VBA script to open the .csv and integrate it into the workbook, and then call that script from within python after you generate the .csv.

Comment: openpyxl can be used to edit existing files and will generally keep existing formatitng.